# All threads are not running with QThread along with QtSerialPort (for Arduino) and Matplotlib

Tags: python, multithreading, matplotlib, arduino, pyqt

I'm trying to get an output from an arduino to be updated in two pyqt windows, one of which is a matplotlib plot. If I comment out the non-plot thread window, the plot works. But when I try to run both at the same time, I get the message

```
3 Device is already open
3 Device is already open
```

but nothing shows up in the plot, though the window is there. Whereas the non-plot window is updated with values. I'm not sure if I should use QThreadpool instead of QThread. On a side note, if I try to rerun the code, I get the message

```
2 Access is denied.
2 Access is denied.
2 Access is denied.
```

so I have to unplug and replug in the arduino, uploading its code again, before running the python script again, and neither window is updated with values.
The arduino code I use, to just give signals over 1 second intervals, to test it out, is

```
int PinOutput = 13;
int PinInput = A0;
int inph;
int inpl;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(PinInput, INPUT);
pinMode(PinOutput, OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
inpl = analogRead(PinInput)/4;
Serial.println(inpl);
analogWrite(PinOutput,255);
delay(1000);
inph = analogRead(PinInput)/4;
Serial.println(inph);
analogWrite(PinOutput,0);
delay(1000);
}
```

Where pin 13 is connected to A0 on the arduino.
The python code is

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore,  QtWidgets, QtSerialPort

from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg

seril_port_connection = QtSerialPort.QSerialPort("COM3")
seril_port_connection.setBaudRate(QtSerialPort.QSerialPort.Baud9600)

class MyThread2(QtCore.QThread):
    ard_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.serial_port = seril_port_connection
        self.serial_port.errorOccurred.connect(self.handle_error)
        self.serial_port.readyRead.connect(self.run)
        self.serial_port.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadWrite)
        
    def run(self):

        while self.serial_port.canReadLine():
            line = self.serial_port.readLine().data().decode().strip().strip('\x00')

            try:
                self.ard_signal.emit(str(line))

            except ValueError as e:
                print("error", e)
        
    def handle_error(self, error):
        if error == QtSerialPort.QSerialPort.NoError:
            return
        print(error, self.serial_port.errorString())

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(325, 237)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 20, 61, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 60, 104, 71))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 150, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 325, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "test window"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "pyqt5 tests"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "test button"))
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.label_change)  
        self.thread_start = MyThread()
        self.thread_start.ard_signal.connect(self.label.setText)        
        self.thread_start.start()
    
  
    def label_change(self):
        self.pushButton.setText('Button Clicked!')
        self.textEdit.setText('taco')

class MainWindowm(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindowm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasQTAgg(Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.canvas)

        self.axes = self.canvas.figure.subplots()

        n_data = 10
        self.xdata = list(range(n_data))
        self.ydata = [0 for i in range(n_data)]

        self.thread_start = MyThread2()
        self.thread_start.ard_signal.connect(self.update_plot)
        self.thread_start.start()
        
    def handle_error(self, error):
        if error == QtSerialPort.QSerialPort.NoError:
            return
        print(error, self.serial_port.errorString())

    def update_plot(self, value):
        self.ydata = self.ydata[1:] + [float(value)]
        self.axes.cla()
        self.axes.plot(self.xdata, self.ydata, "r")
        self.canvas.draw()

class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    ard_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.serial_port = seril_port_connection
        self.serial_port.errorOccurred.connect(self.handle_error)
        self.serial_port.readyRead.connect(self.run)
        self.serial_port.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadWrite)
        
    def run(self):

        while self.serial_port.canReadLine():
            line = self.serial_port.readLine().data().decode().strip().strip('\x00')
            try:
                self.ard_signal.emit(str(line))
            except ValueError as e:
                print("error", e)
        
    def handle_error(self, error):
        if error == QtSerialPort.QSerialPort.NoError:
            return
        print(error, self.serial_port.errorString())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    w = MainWindowm()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

So I'm trying to make the arduino output available globally, to then be used by different threads at the same time, being updated in two windows, one with a plot. Any info on how to do this would help, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the OP is using [my old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63361542/6622587), and in that solution indicate that the use of QSerialPort avoids the unnecessary use of threads, and this also applies in this case. On the other hand, a serial port cannot be handled by several classes. In this case, you just have to create a class that manages the serial port and distributes the information to the other elements.

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtSerialPort

from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(325, 237)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 20, 61, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 60, 104, 71))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 150, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 325, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "test window"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "pyqt5 tests"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "test button"))


class MainWindowm(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindowm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasQTAgg(Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.canvas)

        self.axes = self.canvas.figure.subplots()

        n_data = 10
        self.xdata = list(range(n_data))
        self.ydata = [0 for i in range(n_data)]

    def update_plot(self, value):
        self.ydata = self.ydata[1:] + [value]
        self.axes.cla()
        self.axes.plot(self.xdata, self.ydata, "r")
        self.canvas.draw()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def update_text(self, value):
        self.label.setNum(value)
        self.label.adjustSize()


class SerialManager(QtCore.QObject):
    valueChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(float)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.serial_port = QtSerialPort.QSerialPort("COM3")
        self.serial_port.setBaudRate(QtSerialPort.QSerialPort.Baud9600)
        self.serial_port.errorOccurred.connect(self.handle_error)
        self.serial_port.readyRead.connect(self.handle_ready_read)
        self.serial_port.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadWrite)

    def handle_ready_read(self):
        while self.serial_port.canReadLine():
            codec = QtCore.QTextCodec.codecForName("UTF-8")
            line = codec.toUnicode(self.serial_port.readLine()).strip().strip("\x00")
            try:
                print(line)
                value = float(line)
            except ValueError as e:
                print("error", e)
            else:
                self.valueChanged.emit(value)

    def handle_error(self, error):
        if error == QtSerialPort.QSerialPort.NoError:
            return
        print(error, self.serial_port.errorString())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w1 = MainWindow()
    w1.show()

    w = MainWindowm()
    w.show()

    manager = SerialManager()
    manager.valueChanged.connect(w1.update_text)
    manager.valueChanged.connect(w.update_plot)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```